# Finding the max date between few date columns in each row - POWER BI

Tags: date, powerbi, max, dax

I assume my data looks like this (column names):

```
name (String)
age (Whole Number)
date1 (Date)
date2 (Date)
date3 (Date)
date4 (Date)
gender (String)
```

I would like to add a new column to the table that will contain the MAX date in each row between the dates (date1, date2, date3, date4).

example:
Tami 16 1/2/2020 2/2/2020 4/2/2020 null female --> 4/2/2020 (new calculated column).

Can't find a way to make it in Power BI using DAX.

Comment: Find some cool tricks for Power query editor here - https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Get-MAX-value-of-dates-across-multiple-columns/td-p/614305

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 3 nested `MAX` functions. `MAX(YourTable[date1], MAX(YourTable[date2], MAX(YourTable[date3], YourTable[date4])))`.